Chrome Extension Error Content Security Policy
I am receiving 2 errors in console regarding my chrome extension for an image that follows the cursor around.
This is my manifest.json:
{
  "name": "Custom Cursor Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "description": "Adds a custom cursor on developer.chrome.com.",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "/background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "css": ["style.css"]
    }
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "image.png"
  },

   "content_security_policy": {
    "script-src": ["'self'", "https://www.gstatic.com", "'unsafe-eval'"], 
    "object-src": ["'self'"],
    "img-src": ["'self'", "data:", "https://www.gstatic.com"]
   }
}

Console Error messages
Image not loading

ManifestV3 doesn't allow external code and you can't add it to CSP. Why do you need it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@woxxom v3 allows external code (I use it in two of my sideloads).  It's when you try to publish it on [Insert Store of your choice here], that they'll drag you across the coals :)

ManifestV3 doesn't allow external code in extension's own contexts by design. The exceptions are the unprivileged contexts such as userscript/main world and sandbox. Specifically, content_security_policy doesn't allow external scripts. There is a bug in ManifestV3 that allows importing external scripts but that's a bug so abusing it is a temporary hack.
